# Django Images not uploading via S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I am attempting to upload files to s3 via s3 from this [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/). I created a group and and user with full s3 privilege's and when i upload an image it stays local instead of being uploaded to bucket. block all public access is false on the bucket boto is installed as well as django-storages added to the apps. Having a hard time figuring out the issue as i don't have any error messages to work with any help would be great!

settings.py

```
USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('...')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('...')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('...')
    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_coreyYT.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),)
```

storage_backends.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
    default_acl = 'public-read'


class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = False
```

bucket CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::.../*"
        }
    ]
}
```

model:

```
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
```

view:

```
def createPostView(request):

    postForm = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if len(request.FILES.getlist('images')) > 30:
            raise Exception("Max of 30 images allowed")
        else:        
            if postForm.is_valid():
                PostFormID = postForm.save(commit=False)
                PostFormID.author = request.user
                PostFormID.save()                       
                if len(request.FILES.getlist('images')) == 0:
                    return redirect('post-detail', PostFormID.pk)
                else:
                    for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):          
                        test = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                        if test.is_valid():
                            instance = test.save(commit=False)
                            instance.post_id = PostFormID.id
                            instance.images = f
                            instance.save()   
                return redirect('post-detail', PostFormID.pk)
```

Comment: Show us the view code that actually performs the upload.

Comment: @JohnGordon added view and model working with `postForm`

Comment: I still don't see where the file gets uploaded to S3.  Are you expecting the `.save()` form method to do that automatically?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes I thought it did. Going to go back through the tutorial